# CSS Class on end MySQL row

Tags: php, mysql, css, class

I am having trouble creating a solution that will target the end row of a MySQL query. Currently I have a foreach function that works through the query and displays each one as a div with the information inside:

```
<?php $residents = Resident::find_all();
foreach($residents as $resident): ?>
<div class="submenu">
<p class="menuitem submenuheader"><?php echo $resident->name; ?></p>
<img src="images/<?php echo $resident->image_path(); ?>" width="250" class="image" />
<p><?php echo $resident->info; ?></p>
</div>
```

.submenu currently has a bottom border. I need to remove this on the last row returned. I have looked at DESC LIMIT 1, however this requires another MySQL query and could make things very messy...

Comment: How about using jQuery to remove it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Addd this to your CSS:

```
.submenu:last-child { border-bottom: 0; }
```

**Note**: this is not supported by IE < 9.

Comment: Not supported in IE versions before 9.

Answer (score 1):

You could switch to putting the border on the top of the element, and use the `:first-child` pseudo selector in CSS to remove it.

http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-firstchild

The `:last-child` selector would be nice, but it's not supported in IE before version 9, so it's not a good idea to use it if you want compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you separate your HTML and PHP a little this is easily achieved:

```
<?php 
function echoBlock($resident,$pClass="menuitem submenuheader") {
  echo "<div class=\"submenu\">\n<p class=\"$pClass\">\n";
  echo $resident->name;
  echo "</p>\n<img src=\"images/";
  echo $resident->image_path();
  echo "\" width=\"250\" class=\"image\" />\n<p>";
  echo $resident->info;
  echo "</p>\n</div>\n\n";
}

$residents = Resident::find_all();
$last=count($residents)-1;//2 element array last pos is 1
for ($i=0;$i<$last;$i++) {
  echoBlock($residents[$i]);
}
echoBlock($residents[$last],"menuitem");
?>
```

`echoBlock` (which could easily be a method on a class) requires the calling code to know about the classes it uses, which isn't really separating intent but it does prevent the need for an `if` branch on every loop.  That being said it would be less efficient but perhaps more usable to set it up as:

```
function echoBlock($resident,$isLast=false) {
  $pClass="menuitem".($isLast?"":" submenuheader");
  //...
```

Which then doesn't need the caller to know anything about what `echoBlock` does.

Answer (score 0):

You could try and `pop` the array using [`array_pop()`](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-pop.php), to get the last value out of the array and then inputing it using the special class after the foreach loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about

Instead of echo'ing each line one by one, create one big string in PHP, search for the last entry of "submenu" and change the class.